# Usage-Metrics for ASP.NET Web Services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-hosting, metrics, usage-statistics

Is there a way to collect usage metrics of an ASP.NET web service like Google Analytics collect usage metrics of a web site. All without implementing my own database tables or code.

I don't need to collect the huge amount of information collected by Google Analytics, only simple information, like the number of calls and their distribution over time.

If no external tool can be used, how to simply process the request to a web service to extract information like request location, request source, and other information that could be collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hosting your service in an IIS web server (which I persume you do), you can always check the IIS web server application log, all requests are written to that file.

Open the *.log file and copy the contents to Excel, and use Excel to pivot/group/filter/sort the data so that you present the count (the number of requests) to the web service in a meanigful manner.

Comment: Thanks, I just enabled IIS logging on my web server, it'll take a while before I can get some results. Meanwhile, I'll try searching for some sample log files to get a feeling for what information they can offer.